# Comparing two sentences in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I have a program

```
set signal="Normal Completion of program MRGGRID"`

if ( $signal == "Normal Completion of program MRGGRID" ) then
  echo "yes"
endif
```

The error message is

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the `$signal` variable in the `if`.

`tcsh` expands variables before using them; it's probably best to not think of them as "variables", but more as "macro's", which get expanded before use, so your `if` statement is interpreted as:

```
if ( Normal Completion of program MRGGRID == "Normal Completion of program MRGGRID" )
```

And *not* as:

```
if ( "Normal Completion of program MRGGRID" == "Normal Completion of program MRGGRID" )
```

This is not `tcsh` specific, Bourne shells also work like this... But `tcsh`'s error message are almost universally unhelpful (as you've seen), which is one reason why it's generally discouraged to use `tcsh` for scripting purposes.

Comment: You could also use `$signal:q` rather than `"$signal"`.